# Xamarin.InAppBilling - OnActivityResult - What RequestCodes to filter on?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, in-app-billing

I am working on using Google In-App Billing in a Xamarin Android app, using the Xamarin.InAppBilling component.

I am working on receiving the result of the purchase. The documentation says:

> To complete the purchase cycle, you will need to override the
>   OnActivityResult method of the Activity of the app that initiated the
>   purchase and pass the result to the HandleActivityResult method of the
>   BillingHandler of your open InAppBillingServiceConnection:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    // Ask the open service connection's billing handler to process this request
    _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.HandleActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // TODO: Use a call back to update the purchased items
    // or listen to the OnProductPurchased event to
    // handle a successful purchase
}
```

My issue is that my activity that initiates the purchase also starts other activities besides the Google Play purchase activity. I already have an OnActivityResult method for these other activities. So, I don't want to call BillingHandler.HandleActivityResult() in every case. I need to know whether this is from a Google Play purchase, or something else.

Is there a particular requestCode or range of requestCodes that the Google Play purchase uses that I can filter on?